# How to pass the request body with multi level data using rest-assured

Tags: rest, rest-assured

Trying to send the request body with multi level data using rest-assured in the following way.

Request body:

```
{
  "phoneNumber":1217071016,
  "details":
  [
    {
            "id":"123",
        "name":"New",
        "email":"hello@gmail.com"
    },

    {
         "id":"234",
      "name":"next",
      "email":"next@gmail.com"
    }


  ]

}
```

> @Test     public void generateToken() {
>
> ```
>   Map<String,String> userDetails = new HashMap<>();
>
>   userDetails.put("phoneNumber", "1217071016");
>   userDetails.put("details.Id", "241342");
>   userDetails.put("details.name", "New Name");
>   userDetails.put("details.email", "eclipse@test.com");
>
>           Response response = given()
>
>           .contentType("application/json")
>
>           .queryParam("access_token", "LL6rX8LRP7")
>
>           .body(userDetails)
>
>           .post("http://site/rest/try/update");
> ```
>
> }

When sent in the above way, getting the bad request.

How to pass this kind of data in the above code

Comment: Have you turned on logging for requests and response? How exactly do they look like?

Comment: @RocketRaccoon not logging the request. Not sure how to print the request. Can you guide me

Comment: Use `given().log().all()`

Comment: Body is like `{
    "msISDN": "1217071016",
    "rms.rmEmail": "eclipse@test.com",
    "rms.rmId": "241342",
    "rms.rmLastName": "fjkenrfiw",
    "rms.rmFirstName": "New Name"
}` instead of like the body given above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not a `Map<String, String>` but a `Map<String, Object>`:

```
Map<String, Object> userDetails = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Object> details = new HashMap<>();

details.put("id", "241342");
details.put("name", "New Name");
details.put("email", "eclipse@test.com");

userDetails.put("phoneNumber", "1217071016");
userDetails.put("details", Arrays.asList(details, details));
```

Comment: still the body is getting constructed in wrong way. 

Body:
`{
    "email": "eclipse@test.com",
    "name": "fjkenrfiw",
    "id": "4434353535543"
}`

Comment: it seems you are putting only `details` map to request, it should be `userDetails`

Comment: sorry missed that. these braces [ ]are not getting populated in the body. If they get populated then the body should be correct.

`{
    "phoneNumber": "1217071016",
    "details": {
        "email": "eclipse@test.com",
        "name": "fjkenrfiw",
        "id": "4434353535543"
    }
}` Also the order of the body is getting changed. Is there anyway to sort this.

Comment: just use Array as value, fixed in answer